# KnowRob doc - srdl2_tutorial (can't get the same result)

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My ros version is fuerte and I installed the knowrob stack by "apt-get install ros-fuerte-knowrob".

I ran "rosrun rosprolog rosprolog mod_srdl"

```
% library(swi_hooks) compiled into pce_swi_hooks 0.00 sec, 2,224 bytes

%     library(error) compiled into error 0.00 sec, 10,220 bytes

%    library(lists) compiled into lists 0.01 sec, 25,320 bytes

%   library(shlib) compiled into shlib 0.01 sec, 37,148 bytes

%   library(option) compiled into swi_option 0.00 sec, 8,468 bytes

%  library(process) compiled into process 0.01 sec, 55,748 bytes

% /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/rosprolog/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.01 sec, 60,268 bytes

%   library(jpl) compiled into jpl 0.02 sec, 171,564 bytes

%       library(sgml) compiled into sgml 0.01 sec, 24,220 bytes

%         library(quintus) compiled into quintus 0.00 sec, 11,676 bytes

%        rewrite compiled into rewrite 0.00 sec, 19,112 bytes

%        library(uri) compiled into uri 0.00 sec, 8,036 bytes

%        library(record) compiled into record 0.00 sec, 18,936 bytes

%       rdf_parser compiled into rdf_parser 0.01 sec, 85,024 bytes

%        library(gensym) compiled into gensym 0.00 sec, 2,580 bytes

%       rdf_triple compiled into rdf_triple 0.00 sec, 21,524 bytes

%      library(rdf) compiled into rdf 0.02 sec, 149,888 bytes

%       library(debug) compiled into prolog_debug 0.00 sec, 12,180 bytes

%       library(assoc) compiled into assoc 0.00 sec, 19,484 bytes

%      library(sgml_write) compiled into sgml_write 0.00 sec, 66,928 bytes

%      library(nb_set) compiled into nb_set 0.00 sec, 3,400 bytes

%       library(utf8) compiled into utf8 0.00 sec, 7,108 bytes

%      library(url) compiled into url 0.00 sec, 62,812 bytes

%      rdf_cache compiled into rdf_cache 0.00 sec, 9,016 bytes

%     library(semweb/rdf_db) compiled into rdf_db 0.04 sec, 388,832 bytes

%    comp_similarity compiled into comp_similarity 0.04 sec, 405,148 bytes

%   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_prolog_addons/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.04 sec, 407,180 bytes

%    library(broadcast) compiled into broadcast 0.00 sec, 4,156 bytes

%   library(semweb/rdf_edit) compiled into rdf_edit 0.01 sec, 48,176 bytes

%   library(semweb/rdfs) compiled into rdfs 0.00 sec, 14,256 bytes

%   library(semweb/owl) compiled into t20_owl 0.01 sec, 37,936 bytes

%     library(socket) compiled into socket 0.00 sec, 7,012 bytes

%     library(base64) compiled into base64 0.00 sec, 9,640 bytes

%    library(http/http_open.pl) compiled into http_open 0.01 sec, 58,700 bytes

%   library(thea/owl_parser) compiled into owl_parser 0.02 sec, 105,276 bytes

%    library(odbc) compiled into odbc 0.00 sec, 21,508 bytes

%   library(semweb/rdfs_computable) compiled into rdfs_computable 0.00 sec, 57,604 bytes

%  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.10 sec, 874,864 bytes

%       library(tf_prolog) compiled into tf_prolog 0.01 sec, 13,080 bytes

%      /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/tf_prolog/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.01 sec, 15,428 bytes

%       library(knowrob_owl) compiled into knowrob_owl 0.00 sec, 7,420 bytes

%       library(knowrob_perception) compiled into knowrob_perception 0.01 sec, 13,176 bytes

% Parsed "knowrob_objects.owl" in 0.00 sec; 202 triples

Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_objects/prolog/knowrob_objects.pl:84:

    Goal (directive) failed: knowrob_objects:owl_parser:owl_parse(../owl/knowrob_objects.owl,false,false,true)

%      library(knowrob_objects) compiled into knowrob_objects 0.02 sec, 108,844 bytes

%       library(owl_export) compiled into owl_export 0.00 sec, 11,944 bytes

%      library(knowrob_coordinates) compiled into knowrob_coordinates 0.01 sec, 22,856 bytes

%     /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_objects/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.04 sec, 159,544 bytes

%    /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_common/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.04 sec, 168,460 bytes

%    library(knowrob_actions) compiled into knowrob_actions 0.00 sec, 7,012 bytes

%   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_actions/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.05 sec, 185,720 bytes

%    library(util) compiled into util 0.00 sec, 15,440 bytes

%   library(classifiers) compiled into classifiers 0.00 sec, 29,908 bytes

%   library(jython) compiled into jython 0.00 sec, 13,348 bytes

% Parsed "owl.owl" in 0.00 sec; 169 triples

Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/prolog/init.pl:35:

    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/owl.owl,false,false,true)

% Parsed "knowrob.owl" in 0.07 sec; 3,763 triples

Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/prolog/init.pl:36:

    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/knowrob.owl,false,false,true)

%  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.12 sec, 439,188 bytes

% Parsed "srdl2-action.owl" in 0.01 sec; 78 triples

Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/mod_srdl/prolog/srdl2.pl:39:

    Goal (directive) failed: srdl2:owl_parser:owl_parse(../owl/srdl2-action.owl,false,false,true)

% Parsed "PR2.owl" in 0.01 sec; 771 triples

Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/mod_srdl/prolog/srdl2.pl:40:

    Goal (directive) failed: srdl2:owl_parser:owl_parse(../owl/PR2.owl,false,false,true)

%  library(srdl2) compiled into srdl2 0.02 sec, 46,052 bytes

% /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/mod_srdl/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.24 sec, 1,372,112 bytes

?-
```

There seems no problems expect 5 Warnings. Then I follow the tutorial.

[I delete the link like words for my karma is insufficient to publish links. Orz]

```
?- srdl2:sub_component('TUM_Rosie.owl#TUM_Rosie1',Sub).
false.

?- srdl2:comp_type_available('TUM_Rosie.owl#TUM_Rosie1',CompT).
false.

?- srdl2:cap_available_on_robot(Cap,'TUM_Rosie.owl#TUM_Rosie1').
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#Capability' ;
false.

?- srdl2:required_comp_for_action('TableSetting.owl#TableSetting',Cap).
false.
```

Why can't I get the same result as follows.

```
?- srdl2:sub_component(tumrosie:'TUM_Rosie1', Sub).
Sub = 'TUM_Rosie.owl#TUM_Rosie_WheeledOmnidirPlatform1' ;
Sub = 'TUM_Rosie.owl#TUM_Rosie_Torso1' .

?- srdl2:comp_type_available(tumrosie:'TUM_Rosie1', CompT).
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#VectorFieldArmController' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ArmMotionController' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#MotionControllerComponent' ;
...

?- srdl2:cap_available_on_robot(Cap, tumrosie:'TUM_Rosie1').
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#ArmMotionCapability' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#BaseMotionCapability' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#GripperMotionCapability' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#HeadMotionCapability' ;
...
```

Then I try the PR2.owl. Though I get some results, they look weird.

```
?- srdl2:sub_component('PR2.owl#PR2Robot1',Sub).
Sub = 'PR2.owl#PR2_BaseComposition' ;
Sub = 'PR2.owl#PR2_l_ArmComposition' ;
Sub = 'PR2.owl#PR2_r_ArmComposition' ;
Sub = 'PR2.owl#PR2_l_GripperComposition' ;
Sub = 'PR2.owl#PR2_r_GripperComposition' ;
Sub = 'PR2.owl#LeftArmController' ;
Sub = 'PR2.owl#RightArmController' ;
false.

?- srdl2:comp_type_available('PR2.owl#PR2Robot1',CompT).
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ComponentComposition' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#Pr2Base' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ComponentComposition' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#Pr2Base' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = '__file:///opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/owl.owl#__Description1' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ComponentComposition' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#Pr2Arm' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ComponentComposition' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#Pr2Arm' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = '__file:///opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/owl.owl#__Description1' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ComponentComposition' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#Pr2Arm' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ComponentComposition' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#Pr2Arm' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = '__file:///opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/owl.owl#__Description1' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ComponentComposition' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#Pr2Gripper' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ComponentComposition' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#Pr2Gripper' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = '__file:///opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/owl.owl#__Description1' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ComponentComposition' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#Pr2Gripper' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ComponentComposition' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#Pr2Gripper' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = '__file:///opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/owl.owl#__Description1' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ArmMotionController' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ArmMotionController' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = '__file:///opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/owl.owl#__Description1' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ArmMotionController' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'srdl2-comp.owl#ArmMotionController' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#NamedIndividual' ;
CompT = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
CompT = 'owl#Thing' ;
CompT = '__file:///opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/owl.owl#__Description1' ;
false.

?- srdl2:cap_available_on_robot(Cap,'PR2.owl#PR2Robot1').
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#ClosingADoorCapability' ;
Cap = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#OpeningADoorCapability' ;
Cap = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#GraspingCapability' ;
Cap = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#move_arm' ;
Cap = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#move_base' ;
Cap = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#ClosingADoorCapability' ;
Cap = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#OpeningADoorCapability' ;
Cap = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#GraspingCapability' ;
Cap = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#move_arm' ;
Cap = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#move_base' ;
Cap = 'rdf-schema#Resource' ;
Cap = 'srdl2-cap.owl#Capability' ;
false.
```

Is it the problem of the owl files?

Can anybody help me? Thank you, and sorry for my poor English.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105751/knowrob-doc---srdl2_tutorial-(can%27t-get-the-same-result)/) by [fuchangjie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9291/fuchangjie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned in the [installation instructions](http://www.knowrob.org/installation#installation_from_binary_packages_on_ubuntu_linux), the Fuerte packages are broken. Some global paths have not been adapted, that's why you get these weird errors. Since no new releases for Fuerte are possible, this cannot be fixed. You can, however, easily [install KnowRob from source](http://www.knowrob.org/installation#installation_from_source), which runs on Fuerte, Groovy and Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fuchangjie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9291/fuchangjie/) on 2013-11-28**:
Thanks for your advise, I'll try it later.

**Comment by [fuchangjie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9291/fuchangjie/) on 2013-12-03**:
Hi friend, could you tell me your email or any other contact methods that we can communicate conveniently. I'm a rookie, and wanna learn from you. Thank you.